# How to exclude transitive dependency in Sbt ( in context of assembly plugin )?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two Sbt projects, **my-commons** and **my-service**.

#### my-commons

with the dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka" % "attributeSelectionSearchMethods" % "1.0.7",
  "de.bwaldvogel" % "liblinear" % "1.95"
  "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-graphite" % "3.1.2",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "1.1.0-cdh5.4.5",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0-cdh5.4.5",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.0-cdh5.4.5"
)
```

#### my-service:

with the dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13",
    "io.spray" %% "spray-httpx" % "1.3.3",
    "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.2",
    "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % "1.3.3",
    "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % "1.3.3",
    "io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % "1.3.3" % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.9",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.9" % "test",
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.3.11" % "test",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" %  "3.2.11",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" %  "3.2.11",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.8.4" % "test",
    "com.mycommon.projects" % "my-commons" % "1.0.+"
  )
```

I'm using the assembly sbt plugin

```
   addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

I'm getting error on sbt assembly:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/pom.properties
[error] /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/parquet-hadoop-bundle/jars/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.4.5.jar:META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/pom.properties
```

I've tried to exclude those libs from build but with no success.

```
libraryDependencies ~= { _ map {
  case m if m.organization.startsWith("org.apache") || m.organization.startsWith("com.twitter") || m.name.contains("parquet") =>
   m.exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-api").
   exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")
   case m => m
 }}
```

Probably I'm doing something wrong... How can I resolve this dependency hell?

Comment: Can you provide your Build.scala and project hierarchy?

Comment: This are the parts of build.sbt. The two projects are not hierarchical

Comment: So why `my-service` has dependency on my-common?    `"com.mycommon.projects" % "my-commons" % "1.0.+"`

Comment: Are the two projects inside the same dir? Different folder for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, files exist with different content and thus can't be merged with SBT assembly plugin.

Two approaches possible

#### Approach 1:

Use the merge filter of the assembly plugin to specify, which files to keep, e.g.

```
val sharedMergeStrategy: (String => MergeStrategy) => String => MergeStrategy =
  (old: (String) => MergeStrategy) => {
    case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA") => MergeStrategy.last
    case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/mailcap") => MergeStrategy.last
    case x if x.endsWith("plugin.properties") => MergeStrategy.last
    case x => old(x)
  }
```

#### Approach 2:

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies on how to exclude transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried excludes and it didn't worked. Could you please enchance on what shoul I define and use in buid.sbt, plugins to use merge filter.

Comment: That very much depends on your requirements. First, get confident with the merge strategy in general. Second,  when it comes to merge conflicts, add a rule, that diiscards the wrong file and follow this step subsequently until no more conflicts arise. When this does not result in a solution, think of the transitive dependencies and try to eliminate them beforehand by discarding those not required.

Comment: Apart from that: Why do you definitely need a fat-jar or uber-jar? Can't you use http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/ ( Native Packager) to package everything?

Answer (score 3):

When sbt-assembly merge the packages sometimes there are conflicts because of the chosen strategy. Since those two files have the same name but different contents sbt-assembly can't do anything. This is the default strategy: `deduplicate`.

Probably the best solution is to specify another [merge strategy](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy), in this case, `first` would be the best option.

In your `assembly.sbt` (in the root) (not `project/assembly.sbt`) put the following:

```
import AssemblyKeys._ 

assemblySettings

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {
    case PathList("META-INF", "maven", "org.slf4j", "slf4j-api", "pom.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList("META-INF", "maven", "org.slf4j", "slf4j-api", "pom.xml") => MergeStrategy.first
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I'm pretty new to scala...Could you please add an example

Comment: I tried to reproduce your project here locally, to provide the exact snippet, but I couldn't. I really need to understand how is your project like, folder structure and files (No need to include code sources, though). For example the dependency `"com.mycommon.projects" % "my-commons" % "1.0.+"`  doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If you can update the answer with this info maybe I can help you more with this

Comment: Sure, I'm using my-commons as separate git repo. I'm building it with sbt package publishLocal (or publishM2). Then I'm building the my-service jar