# Deduplicate: Different File Contents Found Error for SBT and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to build a JAR file through SBT, with my driver script being in Scala. However, when I run 'sbt assembly' I receive a large slew of:

```
deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
```

The entire list of directories displaying that message is too large to post here, so I attached a screenshot which you can view below. My build file contains the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided", "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.0")
```

I attempted the solution offered by Onilton Maciel to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463936/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency-in-sbt-in-context-of-assembly-plugin), but to no avail. I am also confused as to how to implement the solution offered by Martin Senne, as the setup instructions on the 'Setup' section for the Assembly plugin are not clear on how to implement his code snippet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I think if you upload text error is better than upload an error picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as the setup instructions on the 'Setup' section for the Assembly plugin are not clear on how to implement his code snippet.

It means you should add **merge strategy** in `build.sbt` or in **root directory sbt files**.

There is an example from [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy) official document and update it with your conflicts:

```
import sbtassembly.MergeStrategy
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "hadoop", "yarn", "factories", "package-info.class")         => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("org", "apache", "hadoop", "yarn", "provider", "package-info.class")         => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("org", "apache", "hadoop", "util", "provider", "package-info.class")         => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class")         => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Hopeful it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks chengpohi! The solution is indeed helpful. I added your code snippet to my build.sbt file, and received a scala.MatchError. I then followed the solution offered in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509450/assemblymergestrategy-causing-scala-matcherror-when-compiling) - as I believe I was missing a default case. However, after adding the default case, I received another slew of the same original de-duplicate error. I believe this is because there were many other dependencies I had no configured MergeStrategy for. What would you recommend?

Comment: I made a slight variation to your code by adding '  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last' and the build now works. Thanks!